# Silverlight/WPF: Retreiving the size of a UIElement once it has been rendered on screen

Tags: wpf, silverlight, size, element

I have the following simple piece of code:

```
            var canvas = new Canvas();

            foreach (var ztring in strings)
            {
                var textblock = new TextBlock();
                textblock.Text = ztring;

                panel.Children.Add(textblock);

                textblock.Measure(infiniteSize);
            }
```

At this point I would expect any of the size properties **(Height/Width, ActualHeight/ActualWidth, DesiredSize, RenderSize)** to give me the size of the textblock. None of them do.

`ActualHeight` always gives `16.0` no matter what size font. `ActualWidth` changes according to the text length but not the font size.

I change the font size on the parent container and not the `TextBlock` itself.

I feel like I am missing some basic element of understanding the manipulation of silverlight elements from within the codebehind.

The question is: how do I get **the real actual pixel size** of my `TextBlock`?

Comment: 1k views and only one up-vote? come on guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a sample that adds a `TextBlock` to a `Canvas` using code behind and once the `TextBlock` is rendered, it displays its height in the title of the window. Is that what you are looking for?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="HeightTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel TextBlock.FontSize="30">
        <Canvas Name="_canvas" Height="200"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace HeightTest
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = "Hello";
            Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, 25);
            textBlock.Loaded += 
                (sender, e) => 
                {
                    Title = textBlock.ActualHeight.ToString();
                };
            _canvas.Children.Add(textBlock);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a real container like a `Grid` instead of `Canvas`?
What if you try reading the `ActualSize` property after the Measure using a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`?

Comment: I want to absolute-position the textblocks within the container. For that I use `Canvas.SetLeft()`. I don't think that works for `Grid`.